# 403 error when trying to create a dashboard through python

Tags: python, server, google-colaboratory, dashboard

```
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import pandas as pd
app = Dash(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv("/content/ipl_2023_dataset.csv")
grouped=df.groupby(['Team','Type']).agg({"Price Cr":"sum"} ).reset_index()
f = df.groupby("Team").sum()



fig = px.bar(f, x=f.index, y="Price Cr", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for your data.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I have tried changing the Dash part to JupyterDash, the mode = True to inline.I am not sure if there is a specific version of dash I need. I am just trying to create a simple dashboard.